# put textures in cinema4d

Tags: model, textures, uv-mapping, cinema-4d

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsFQD.png)

I have my obj on scene4d (i downloaded it from internet). When I open it with cinema4d it loads the materials but it doesn't put the textures on the object

Comment: Try to invert/flip face normals: they might be pointing inwards, not outwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can only do it one by one checking the path of each material in your disc

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the textures are in the same location where your c4d file is. Let me know if that's clear, I would post a screenshot but I don't have Cinema on this computer and it would take a bit to start up my work computer.

Comment: I had them on the same folder, the thing is the original path wasn't correct but I only know how to change path on each material one by one, is there any way to change all paths at once?